# Link doesn't let animation to end JQUERY

Tags: jquery, animation, hyperlink

I create a div that when is clicked it executes an jquery script, but the problem I have is that in the animation there is a link, when you click on the link the links is execute as well as the animation but it does not let the animation to end. Is there a way to let know Jquery that when the links its executed wait for the animation to end and then go to the link?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do this using the end animation callback if you using [`jQuery.animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) or similar.  Basically, you'll use have a jQuery.click handler on the link.  In the handler, set a flag (clickedFooLink = true).  Then, return false from the handler (so the default action of navigating immediately isn't taken). Finally, in the end animation callback, if clickedFooLink is true, you navigate then.   Post your source code for more help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the link's `click` event and record the click, then `return false` to prevent the navigation.

Then when the animation finishes, check whether you've recorded a click, and, if so, set `location.href`.

However, I don't recommend doing this.  If a user clicked a link, he obviously wants to go to that page, and he's not interested in your animation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the callback param for the animate function:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({}, 500, function() { location.href = $(this).attr('href') });
    return false;
});
```

This will execute the animation when the link is clicked and will go to the url once the animation has completed.